# Java create generic instance with type parameter obtained at runtime

Tags: java, generics, runtime

I have a class like this:

```
public class Pojo<T, P> {}
```

I know at compile time the type of T but I don't know the type of P. I was wondering if something like this is possible:

```
Class<Integer> t = Integer.class;
field = new Pojo<Integer, t>();
```

If not, any alternative solution to the problem is valid ;)

**EDIT:**
I'm trying to obtain statistics from POJO fields, i.e, I have a class AirRegister with fields station, o3, so2, altitude, latitude... and I want to obtain the mode for these fields. The user can send any type with any field type to the program so until runtime the field type is unknown.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String field = args[0];
    Class<fieldType> type = AirRegister.class.getDeclaredField(field).getClass();
    ModeImpl<AirRegister, type> p = new ModeImpl<AirRegister, type>();
}
```

Comment: Generics were invented to help the compiler ensure proper type checking, _at compile time_ (as opposed to making everything an `Object` and then doing run-time class checks).  A generic with a class that isn't known until run time therefore isn't very useful as a generic.  I can't propose an alternative solution unless I know what you're really trying to accomplish.  For example, what does the inside of your `Pojo` really look like?  What were you hoping would happen when you instantiated your `Pojo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. Generics are a compile-time only feature. They are used by the compiler to type-check your source code, but at run-time they are gone.

If you need to implement run-time type checking, you might use `Class` instances to store the required type. E.g.:

```
class Pojo<T> {
    private Class<?> clazz;
    Pojo(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
    void doSomething(T arg1, Object arg2) {
        if (!clazz.isInstance(arg2)) {
            throw new ClassCastException();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```